# StringIndexOutOfBoundException for unknown reason

Tags: java, string, exception

I have no clue, why I get an `StringIndexOutOfBoundExeption` at this point:

```
for (int i = start; i < dataList.size() - 6
& dataList.get(i + 1).toString().substring(1).equals(lineNumber) 
& !dataList.get(i + 1).toString().substring(1)
                        .equals("LIST_END"); i += 6)
            {
            if (!dataList.get(i).toString().contains("null")){ 
                shortList.add(dataList.get(i).toString()); }
            else {shortList.add("");}

            if (!dataList.get(i+1).toString().contains("null")){
                shortList.add(dataList.get(i + 1).toString());}
            else {shortList.add("");}

            if (!dataList.get(i+2).toString().contains("null")){
                shortList.add(dataList.get(i + 2).toString());}
            else {shortList.add("");}

            if (!dataList.get(i+3).toString().contains("null")){
                shortList.add(dataList.get(i + 3).toString()); }
            else {shortList.add("");}

            if (!dataList.get(i+4).toString().contains("null")){
                shortList.add(dataList.get(i + 4).toString()); }
            else {shortList.add("");}
```

This is inside a loop, which adds the data from this `ArrayList`:

`[null,  00010,  2013,  2.0,  null,` and so on. As you can see, the first and fifth element is null.

When I check the first element, for if it contains `null`, it throws the Exception. 
When I check the fifth element, for if it contains `null`, it doesn't, and displays an empty string `" "` in the UI.

What is the reason for this?

And if I comment the if-statement for the first element out, my UI shows me `null`. (This is code from my android application, the `TextView`, which displays the first element of the `ArrayList` displays `null`)

**EDIT:**

answers to all the comments:

the `dataList.size` is variable, in this case 7

yes, the data is from an SAP interface, but no cursor is used

condition is added

here is the Error message:

> 08-14 11:45:01.725: E/Request(18465):
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1 ,
>   pointing to the line of the if condition of the first element

**EDIT2: **

Again, to specify my problem:

I encounter :

> 08-14 11:45:01.725: E/Request(18465):
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1

But why? There are data in my array, and the same if condition works for the fifth element. Why does it cause an error at the first if condition (according to my Log)

Comment: print the dataList's size.

Comment: Why using contains? Have u tried it using "equals"?

Comment: @Niko any reason you put back the Android tag ?

Comment: Does your Collection dataList have more than (countOfLoop + i + 4) element? You need to iterate from 0 to till (dataList.size - 4)

Comment: Are you querying from db? Are you using cursor?

Comment: dataList.size() is outofsize in one of the condition.

Comment: Can you write your loop condition?

Comment: Include the complete error message in your question. The code you have posted **can not** cause a `StringIndexOutOfBoundExeption`....

Comment: @giorashc I did nothing with tags

Comment: oh, cause I seen in your edit the tag added again. Never mind. I removed it since  the question is not Android related. Its a pure java problem (at least from what he posted so far)

Comment: okay, I am adding your requested information one by one

Comment: `.substring(1)` could cause a `StringIndexOutOfBoundException`.

Comment: @OmriBarel But why? it does not under the same circumstances in the last case

Comment: They are not same circumstances. Data is not the same.

Comment: What I mean is that in all that code, that seems to me the only thing that can generate this exception.

Comment: @OmriBarel Oh, yeah, but as soon as I cancel the first if statement, the whole thing works. So i seems to be another reason for this problem

Comment: @geet Because sometimes, there is a " null" and sometimes a "null", i want to take care of both cases

Comment: The error message says it all: You have a string of length 0, an empty string, `""`, and are trying to call `substring(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i finally found the error, thanks to everyone !

the error was caused by .substring(1) , but not for the reason, that I tried to access an non existing array-field.

As I mentioned, the error does not occur, when I delete the first if-statement

```
if (!dataList.get(i).toString().contains("null"))
```

Everything in this loop works fine, even the replacement of `null`to `""`.

So later on, want to delete the `[` if front of the first attribute, so I use a

```
.substring(1)
```

which of course now fails, for the reason, the string is now `""` .

I did not see that, because as I mentions in my question and comments, my Log points at the loop I posted. And when I tried to debug the code, the program exits at this point.

I can't tell you the reason, why this happens, but at least I know now, what caused the error.

Comment: It should crash at `if (!dataList.get(i+4).toString().contains("null"))` too if your ArrayList is `[null, 00010, 2013, 2.0, null, ...]`

Comment: No, because I try to access the first element with a `.substring(1)` again later, after I replaced `null` with `""`. But not the fifth element. Because the first element has the String bracket `[`, and 'i want to delete it.

Answer (score 3):

The code causing the problem is most likely the condition in the `for` statement:

`dataList.get(i + 1).toString().substring(1)`

This condition will throw an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=1` when `dataList.get(i + 1).toString()` returns an empty string.

Comment: I thougth so, too. But as soon, as I delete the first if-condition ` if (!dataList.get(i).toString().contains("null")`, it works, and the null, which is the fifth element gets replaces with " ". Or am I just not getting something? And the Logcat also points to this line... And for the size, the ArrayList has a size of 7. `start`is 0, therefore this shouldn't be a problem ?! Again, if I am just to stupid to see whats wrong, please tell me.

Comment: And when you debug it, what value does `dataList.get(i + 1)` have just before it throws the exception?

Comment: `i` is 0, therefore it has to be 1, then it jumps into the exception.

Comment: I asked for the value of `dataList.get(i + 1)`, not `i+1`. Run the program in debug mode and check the value of `dataList.get(i + 1)` and `dataList.get(i + 1).toString()`!

Comment: both return `" LIST_END"`, according to the debugger info, with an empty space before the `L`

Answer (score 0):

If `dataList.get(0)` is `null`, you cannot call `toString()` for it, because there's no object so there's no method `toString()` to call. But I don't think it's a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Anyway, you should check for `null` another way - `if (dataList.get(i) != null)`

Comment: You are right, but `null` is a String in this case, this is why I check for `"null"`. I know what you try to explain. But this isn't the null, standing for empty and causes a NullPointerException, but simply a String, which is `"null"`. This is for the reason, I get the data from an interface.

Comment: @AndroidRookie, you need to find out which part of `dataList.get(i).toString().contains("null")` throws an exception. I think that stack trace and some `System.out.println()` calls can help you with it

Comment: I does not anymore. Since I added an if-statement to the mentioned line, to check if the string is `""`, before trying `.substring(1)`, the whole thing works. But thank you for your effort to help me with this ;)